# Replacing code source in programs using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have to locate subprograms in an application under Oracle Forms Builder 6i;and replace a set of values with another ones. 
Is it possible to achieve this using a powershell script ?

Comment: How vague can one be? change words in  _some form_ using _some code_ on _some buttons_

Comment: Sorry i tried my best.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
(Get-Content -path "C:\path to file\file.txt" -Raw) -replace("old value", "new value")
```

Comment: Thanks. The application is under Oracle forms 6i. I have to examine every portion of pl sql code to locate all the old values (values that have to be changed with the new ones)and replace them.